# android: how to fix gps with mock(fake) coordinates?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I'm trying to fix GPS programmatically when the GPS signal is not available. I want to do this in order to provide mock coordinates to other apps like google maps and others. I tried to use GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER but only with the latter I can get a new location valid for google maps. But this works only the first tima and if I want to re-fix more mock locations google maps doesn't see any change... why?? 
I have to do a service for what I want to do?

```
public void setLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {   


     //mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
     mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
     lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     lm.clearTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider);
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(mocLocationProvider,0,0,new llistener());
     lm.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 0, 10);
     lm.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
     Location loc = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
     loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
     loc.setLatitude(latitude);
     loc.setLongitude(longitude);
     loc.setAccuracy(10);
     lm.setTestProviderStatus(mocLocationProvider, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,null, System.currentTimeMillis());
     lm.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, loc);   

}
```

and location listener

```
public class llistener implements LocationListener {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
        Bundle extras) {
}

}
```

thanks

Comment: have you fix this issue? i can also set mock location only once.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What mock locations need :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION">
```

Also in the android phone settings make sure you have the "Allow mock locations" checkbox ticked

```
locationManager.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false,
                    false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
```

.
Now whenever you want to send a location, call this code:

```
Location mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
mockLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());  // double 
mockLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude()); 
mockLocation.setAltitude(location.getAltitude()); 
mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
locationManager.setTestProviderLocation( mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
```

.

> But this works only the first time

Because you called it one time.

> I have to do a service for what I want to do

You can do this, even an AsyncTask will do

> do this or not: lm.requestLocationUpdates()

Yes you have to with the `mocLocationProvider`

> I already call more times the method setLocation(latitude,longitude) but it works(location updateding) only first time for google maps

There is no method called `setLocation()`, use [`setTestLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderLocation%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.Location%29)

> What actually I have to do in asynckTask

You can use a Thread, a TimerTask or anything you like. The idea is to inject location every second into the Framework.

Comment: We say thanks on StackOverflow by upvotes/marking the solution with a green tick. You're welcome.

Comment: I set right permissions. Just other two doubts: 1)I don't need to bind LocationManager on LocationListner for that? 2) Why exactly if I try to recall setLocation manually(so I call LocationManager more than one time) it doesn't work and I have to use the asynktask? What I have to call in asynctask? Thanks a ton

Comment: What do you mean by bind `LocationManager` on `LocationListener`? I did not understand the second question either.

Comment: I mean if I have to do this or not: lm.requestLocationUpdates(mocLocationProvider,0,0,new llistener());
I restate the second question: I already call more times the method setLocation(latitude,longitude) but it works(location updateding) only first time for google maps. What actually I have to do in asynckTask? Do you have any example to better understand what I have to do in asynktask? thank you very much