# Using Appium to automate a Geofencing test

Tags: android, automation, location, automated-tests, appium

**App** : Hotel App - Hotel keeps track of the delivery boy location as they could find the efficiency. 
**Concept** : The Delivery location would be set, If the delivery boys comes within 50 meter radius then the time would be noted and After leaving the 50 meter radius the time would be noted. These records would we used to calculate the efficiency of the delivery boy.
**Help Needed** : To automate this concept in Android app, I will have to change the GPS location of the device. How can I acheive this?. Need inputs from all side.

Comment: That really depends on what you have developed, as far as the Android implementation of Geofence, you can use mock location to provide mock data to internal location system and automate the system

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain That's what I was asking about, How can we mock the location. Need detailed answer here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can always mock the location on Android, there are thousands of examples, one is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8045680/1061944

Comment: Thanks @MurtazaKhursheedHussain , Can u share some more references.