# Mock location won't override actual gps... Am I missing something here? @Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

so this is my code:

```
    public static void SetMockLocation()
    {


        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        var locationManager = context.GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;

        locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test299", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
        locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("Test299", true);

        var location = new Location("Test299");
        location.Latitude = Add700ToCoordinates();
        location.Longitude = GlobalLongitude;
        location.Accuracy = 0; // ob das geht?... ja, aber was beduetet es?  
        location.Time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        location.ElapsedRealtimeNanos = 100;  // hier das gleiche... was hießt es? :D 
        locationManager.SetTestProviderLocation("Test299", location);


        //Do something here? 

        locationManager.RemoveTestProvider("Test299");


    }
```

So I start the app and it works. Now, when I go into google maps, I was hoping it would set me right where my new coordinates show to. But im still getting my original location on maps. What am I missing?

Thanks!

**** EDIT:

I think that it may have something to do with the app not running in the background. If so, how would I get this method to be repeated over and over again even though the app is in the background?

thanks :)

Comment: What happens if you never call `locationManager.RemoveTestProvider("Test299");` ?

Comment: hey! well if i do that, i simply get an exeption saying test299 already exists...

Comment: Have you seen this SO thread on the same topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044208/android-how-to-fix-gps-with-mockfake-coordinates